# Instagram Parse Authentication to generate Session Token Swift IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform, instagram

How do i create the session token required to authenticate a user in parse.
I have been able to follow this blog post http://blog.parse.com/announcements/bring-your-own-login/ but i don't know how to generate a session token using Swift(IOS).

This is what i have so far.

```
func doAuthInstagram() {
    let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey: Instagram["consumerKey"]!,
        consumerSecret: Instagram["consumerSecret"]!,
        authorizeUrl: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize",
        responseType: "token"
    )

    let state: String = generateStateWithLength(20) as String
    oauthswift.authorize_url_handler = WebViewController()

    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL(NSURL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/instagram")!, scope: "likes+comments", state: state,
        success: { (credential, response, parameters) -> Void in

        let url: String = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=\(credential.oauth_token)"
        let parameters: Dictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()

        oauthswift.client.get(url, parameters: parameters,
            success: { (data, response) -> Void in
            let jsonDict: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)

                let user = PFUser()
                if let userData: AnyObject = jsonDict["data"] {
                    let name: String = userData["full_name"] as! String
                    let username: String = userData["username"] as! String
                    let id: String = userData["id"] as! String
                    let profileImage: String = userData["profile_picture"] as! String

                    user.username = username
                    user.password = id
                    user["name"] = name
                    user["profileImage"] = profileImage

                    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
                        if (success) {
                            println("user: \(user)")
                            PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password: id, block: { (user, error) -> Void in
                                if user != nil {
                                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
                                } else {
                                    ProgressHUD.showError("\(error)")
                                }
                            })
                        } else if let error = error!.userInfo!["error"] as? NSString {
                            if error == "username \(username) already taken" {
                                PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password: id, block: { (user, error) -> Void in
                                    if user != nil {
                                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
                                    } else {
                                        ProgressHUD.showError("\(error)")
                                    }
                                })
                            } else {
                                ProgressHUD.showError("\(error)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

        }, failure: { (error) -> Void in
            ProgressHUD.showError("\(error)")
        })
    }) { (error) -> Void in
        println(error.localizedDescription)
        ProgressHUD.showError("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```